# Set background drawable of openGL animation

Tags: android-layout, opengl-es

I'm looking to set a static image from my drawable resource folder as a background for my OpenGL animation. As the animation sits on a `GLSurfaceView` I tried setting the `GLSurfaceView`'s background to the drawable resource but this doesn't work.

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/graphics_glsurfaceview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background" />
```

Any ideas how I would go about setting a background image for my OpenGL animation. I have `onSurfaceCreated`, `onDrawFrame`, `onSurfaceChanged` methods for my `GLSurfaceView` class so maybe somewhere in there?

Comment: @genpfault Why the negative mark? I asked a question which I attempted to answer myself, failed in the process several times, then used the answer provided to achieve the task. I then rightfully accepted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. You will need to make it this way:

1. Place another view with needed background beneath `GLSurfaceView`
2. Use transparent clear color in rendeder.

This way you will see your background.

You can see example of this in Android API Demos, take a look at `TranslucentGLSurfaceViewActivity`. To see it, launch API Demos application and select *Graphics->OpenGL ES->Translucent GLSurfaceView*.

However, I will strongly suggest to draw background not this way but with OpenGL means - load texture and draw it.